# Failed getting height of view in Chrome - backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I am trying to equal the view template div in backbone view.

```
 render: function(options){
        var highestBox = 0;
        this.collection.each(function(_itemData){
            var item = new ItemView({model : _itemData});
            this.$el.append(item.el);
            if (item.$el.height() > highestBox){
                highestBox = item.$el.height();
            }
        },this);
        $('#container .item').height(highestBox + 90);
 }
```

It works well in firefox yet in chrome, it returns `height = 52px` when I do `console.log(highestBox)`   in `this.collection` loop.

I supposed the height of the view will be set to be the highest one, but it didn't.
Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Comment: Causing what exactly?

Comment: @c-smile : I supposed the height of the view will be set to be the highest one, but it didn't.

Comment: Looks fine. Can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue ?

Comment: @coding_idiot : Here's my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460121/equal-height-of-dynamic-column-in-backbone-js/25460577?noredirect=1#comment39730824_25460577, and setting height is in `itemListView` block of the question . Sorry for not creating a fiddle because it is too complicated to do it and I don't know how. Hope you don't mind.. thanks before hand.